# List tooltips show column metadata (description) not repeat name of name of column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, metadata

I am unable to comment on a prior post on this issue and no solution was found, so reposting this ongoing issue in Sharepoint Online 365, hoping for a better answer.

Metadata for Columns in Lists and Libraries are not shown in the hover over tooltip by default...as they are in virtually all other applications. I need the popup to have the column description...but just repeat the name of the column (really no clue why this would be wanted anyway).

Help!

If there is no solution, perhaps someone knows how to export all the columns and their descriptions so I can create an external SOP quickly (not a great solution, but will do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OOB way to change the default behavior, in addition, in the SharePoint online modern list page, we cannot insert the code as described in [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/838034eb-1fe4-4d41-8a62-2343884d0597/tooltip-for-column-headers-in-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointgeneral).

As a workaround, run following powershell to get all fields of a List with description then Export to CSV:(Remember to change the **site url and list name** for yourself)

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
#function to Get all fields from a SharePoint Online list or library
Function Get-SPOListFields()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $ListName
    )
 
    Try {
        $Cred= Get-Credential
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
 
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
         
        #Get the List
        $List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
        $Ctx.Load($List)
        $Ctx.Load($List.Fields)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
         
        #Array to hold result
        $FieldData = @()
        #Iterate through each field in the list
        Foreach ($Field in $List.Fields)
        {  
 
            #Send Data to object array
            $FieldData += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                    'Field Title' = $Field.Title
                    'Field Description' = $Field.Description
                    }
        }
        Return $FieldData
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error Getting Fields from List!" $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
 
#Set parameter values
$SiteURL="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1"
$ListName="list1"
$CSVLocation ="C:\Temp\ListFields.csv"
 
#Call the function to get all list fields
Get-SPOListFields -SiteURL $SiteURL -ListName $ListName | Export-Csv $CSVLocation -NoTypeInformation
```

Result:

[image]

More information for your reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-get-all-list-fields-using-powershell.html